# Angular cli commands seems to be slow

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli, angular13

I am trying to modify an existing Angular application using angular/cli commands. I have tried to create a new component using

```
 'ng generate component new-component'
```

but it was taking too long in cli and a similar `ng add` command also showed the same delay.

My angular/cli version is 13.0.2.

I am not sure why the cli is behaving so.